# Notification with 3 specific recipients

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, notifications

I'm creating a notification with 3 specific receiver. My problem is when 1 receiver view the notification the viewed field will become 1 and when the other receiver log in and view all notification it wont display because its already mark as read.

[image]

Comment: Didn't get, what you are talking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new table `notifications_seen` with columns like `id`,`user_id`,`notification_id`. When you want to know if a user already have seen the notification, just query this table. When the result is `0 rows`, you can display the notification.

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM `notifications_seen` WHERE `user_id` = 1 AND `notification_id` = 13;
$result = $db->query($sql);
if($db->num($result) == 0)
{
  // add code to view notification
  // don't forget to to make an INSERT when the notification was seen
}
```